# Redirecting WEB traffic from one url to another in Tomcat

Tags: iis, tomcat, reverse-proxy

How to forward a website running on example.com:8181(Tomcat Service) to myapp.example.com(In IIS) subdomain which is running on IIS 7 .

If you could outline the specific steps I need to take I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to setup a JavaScript-based redirection from your Tomcat home page. Add this to your index.html or equivalent:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href="myapp.example.com";
</script>
```

I am sure there is a better and more **Tomcat** way of getting it done through rewrite rules like [UrlRewriteFilter](https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/)